# FFT Algo Implementation Issues

Tags: fft

I am trying to implement an FFT in a shader to run on the GPU. I grabbed the algorithm from here:
https://github.com/jbouny/fft-ocean/blob/master/js/shaders/FFTOceanShader.js

However, when implemented and compared with other FFT objects (which I'm doing in max/msp) the results of the above algorithm don't seem to match at all.

Would anyone be able to tell me if there is an issue with the algorithm or implementation? If nothing is wrong with the algorithm then there must be an issue with how I am sending the values or something...

Some points to consider:

1. I am performing the FFT on audio samples which are 1D instead of an image. The input I'm sending it is a window of 1024 audio samples, (ie vec4(sample,0,0,0) ) the dimensions are 1024x1.
2. I don't really understand the Subtransform size and it's hard to find clear info about it from google searching, so I am not sure if I'm setting it correctly.
3. I set the transform size as the FFT size, is that correct?

Here is the algorithm implemented in my shader:

```
const float TWO_PI_NEG = -6.2831853072;
varying vec2 texcoord0;
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform float fftSize = 1024;
uniform float subtransformSize = 4;
uniform float subtransformSizeHalf = 2;
uniform float horizontal = 1;
float fftSizeHalf = fftSize * 0.5;



//
vec2 multiplyComplex (vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    return vec2(a[0] * b[0] - a[1] * b[1], a[1] * b[0] + a[0] * b[1]);
}


//GPU FFT using a Stockham formulation
vec4 fft (
    sampler2D src, 
    vec2 coord,
    float transformSize, 
    float transformSizeHalf,
    float subtransformSize,
    float subtransformSizeHalf,
    float horizontal
) {
    float index;
    if (horizontal == 1) {
        index = coord.x * transformSize - 0.5;
    } else {
        index = coord.y * transformSize - 0.5;
    }

    float evenIndex = floor(index / subtransformSize) * subtransformSizeHalf + mod(index, subtransformSizeHalf);

    //transform two complex sequences simultaneously
    vec4 even;
    vec4 odd;
    if (horizontal == 1) {
        even = texture2D(src, vec2(evenIndex + 0.5, gl_FragCoord.y) / transformSize).rgba;
        odd = texture2D(src, vec2(evenIndex + transformSizeHalf + 0.5, gl_FragCoord.y) / transformSize).rgba;
    } else {
        even = texture2D(src, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, evenIndex + 0.5) / transformSize).rgba;
        odd = texture2D(src, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, evenIndex + transformSizeHalf + 0.5) / transformSize).rgba;
    }

    float twiddleArgument1D = TWO_PI_NEG * (index / subtransformSize);
    vec2 twiddle1D = vec2(cos(twiddleArgument1D), sin(twiddleArgument1D));

    vec2 outputA = even.xy + multiplyComplex(twiddle1D, odd.xy);  //even.xy
    vec2 outputB = even.zw + multiplyComplex(twiddle1D, odd.zw); //even.zw
    return vec4(outputA, outputB);
}



//
void main(void){
    gl_FragColor = fft(tex0, texcoord0, fftSize, fftSizeHalf, subtransformSize, subtransformSizeHalf, 1.);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *"If nothing is wrong with the algorithm then there must be an issue with how I am sending the values or something"*. Please try first with an input for which you know what the FFT output should be (sine wave for example).

Comment: @Jdip The output I get is certainly wrong, and I have three other FFT objects with identical outputs to compare with this one (I send the same input to all of the FFT objects and this algorithm) and this algorithm is the only one with (widely) different output in terms of the values. I will try with a sine tone and see what happens with the result to get clarity (hopefully)

Comment: Yes. The result from a sine tone could very well give you an idea of what the problem is! Let me know when you try ;)

Comment: @Jdip I tried with sin tones and the output is much different. When I convert the output to polar coordinates and view the spectrum, which should just be a single line or point at the frequency bin of the sine tone, it instead is kind of repeating alternating values :/ The subtransform size seems to affect the output a fair amount but I am having trouble understanding what it does exactly and how to size it!

Comment: Ok actually when I view the spectral image of the output for the sine tone it actually gives me a repeating window from 0 to 1 at the frequency of transformSize/subtransfromSize/2 . And if I send in noise values I can see that same windowing pattern attenuating the noise

Comment: Why are you keen on using this particular FFT algorithm?

Comment: I've never coded an FFT and it might be a bit beyond my understanding of how to do it. There are very little GPU shader implementations of it I could find in GLSL, which is what I need (the only other one I found was said to be unoptimized).

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that can implement fft. https://www.fftw.org/ is your best bet.

Comment: @Jdip I see! This is a shader I'm writing and runs on the GPU not CPU so at best I'd probably have to port that library. I am pretty hesitant to code it myself cuz I need it to be pretty fast and optimized, but I might just have to go down that route :/  Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! If I have time I’ll try and see what’s wrong with the code but I don’t have the bandwidth for this at the moment. Maybe someone else will though.

Comment: FYI I was told this algo needs to be recursive or iterated and was linked some solutions in GPU so I think I'll be ok! If anyone is curious these are the links: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsVXWt  and  https://github.com/dli/waves/blob/master/simulation.js#L566-L593